# How to have an object with Text property equal to the character made from an integer from an array

Tags: arrays, freepascal, lazarus

I'm trying to write a short program using Lazarus. I initialise an array of integers; I have a TEdit object X1 whose Text value (after clicking the 'Initialise' button) I want to be equal to the (character made from) first element of the array. Here are the relevant code segments:

```
var
  w: Array[0..3] of Integer = (1,0,1,0);
```

(...)

```
procedure TForm1.InitialiseClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    X1.Text:=InttoStr(w[0]);
  end;
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the following message:

```
unit1.pas(81,22) Error: No default property available
unit1.pas(81,22) Fatal: Syntax error, ")" expected but "[" found
```

with the cursor right at the 'w' after 'InttoStr('.

What am I doing wrong? Googling 'properties of arrays' did not help me much (as you can tell, I'm a newbie...) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is a different "w" is in your scope, e.g. a field of the TForm1 class, or defined as global variable/symbol by an unit USESd in the implementation

In such cases, trying to reduce the source to the minimum example that still exhibits the bug, and then look what makes it finally disappear can shed some light on what is happening.